# Data persistence in GraphRequest with FBSDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

Good afternoon community,

I'm trying to get the data from graphrequest and be able to pass the data to another viewController, but apparently it doesn't get saved in a variable, outside of making the query, the data is removed, it doesn't get saved in a variable.

Have any of you had this problem or something like that?

I leave my code below of my first viewController

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

@IBOutlet var test: UILabel!


var comprobacion = "";

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current(), !token.isExpired {

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = view.center
        loginButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.awakeFromNib()
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        
    }else{
        
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    loginButton.awakeFromNib()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    
    }
    
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    
    let resultado = result?.token?.tokenString
    
    let request = FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: resultado, version: nil, httpMethod: "get")
    
    request?.start(completionHandler: { connection , result, error in
        
        let datos: [String:AnyObject] = result as! [String:AnyObject];
        
        self.comprobacion =  (datos["email"] as! NSString) as String;
        
        print("campos \(String(describing: result) )")
        
        self.test.text = self.comprobacion
        
    })
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self)
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController") as! SecondController
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
     
    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destino = segue.destination as! SecondController
    destino.recibir = comprobacion;
    
}


func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    
    print("GoodBye...   Hommi")
}
}
```

I leave my code below of my second viewController

```
 import UIKit

class SecondController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Email: UILabel!
var recibir: String!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("recibir \(String(describing: recibir))")
  
    Email.text = String(recibir)
}

 }
```

I realized that the email is not saved in my variable, since it is outside the clousure request.start if I print the variable it is empty.

some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-arrange code to

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    
    let resultado = result?.token?.tokenString
    
    let request = FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: resultado, version: nil, httpMethod: "get")
    
    request?.start(completionHandler: { connection , result, error in
        
        let datos: [String:AnyObject] = result as! [String:AnyObject];
        
        self.comprobacion =  (datos["email"] as! NSString) as String;
        
        print("campos \(String(describing: result) )")
        
        self.test.text = self.comprobacion 

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self) 
        }
        
    })
    
    
}
```

Tips

1- Code inside `request?.start(completionHandler` runs asynchnoulsy after the segue so the segue occurs while your var is still nil

2- Don't instantiate a vc and present it when you already use a segue

Comment: Many thanks!.

Isn't there some way to make it appear in a label in another viewController?
Despite the segue and the asynchronous task it is not reflected on my label.